# Updated OS X to 10.7.5, now I can't connect to local PostgreSQL databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, postgresql, osx-lion, homebrew

I'm developing several Rails 3.2 applications on Mac OS X Lion.  Last night, I updated from 10.7.4 to 10.7.5, and I found this morning that I'm no longer able to connect to my development Postgresql databases (while my production environments are working just fine, with the same codebases). This is the case for all applications I'm developing locally which use PostgreSQL.

The error message I'm getting every time I try to connect:

```
PG::Error: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I've read a few other SO posts about similar problems, but most of them suggest `PATH` changes in `~/.bash_profile`.  When I run `which psql` (as suggested in the other posts), though, `/usr/local/bin/psql` is returned, which is correct (according to the other posts).

I'm hesitant to uninstall and reinstall PostgreSQL again (even via Homebrew), as I don't want to mess with my existing PostgreSQL databases for all of my applications.  (Perhaps that's not a potential problem—I'm not confident enough to say.)

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the `pg` gem several times, closed and reopened my shell session, restarted my machine (and every combination thereof), all to no avail.

Where can I go from here?

Comment: Is Homebrew how you installed Pg in the first place? Is the server running (do `postgres` processes show up in the process list) and accepting connections (does "psql" connect either via socket or when given an explicit hostname and port) ?

Comment: Homebrew is how I installed PostgreSQL in the first place (I should've specified that that's the reason my path is `/usr/local/bin/psql`).

The output when I run `ps auxwww | grep postgres` is `jason            2327   0.0  0.0  2432768    588 s000  S+   10:23PM   0:00.00 grep postgres`.

Unsure about the alternative connections at this point—is there a good way to test this? (I'm a relative n00b to PostgreSQL)

Comment: OK, so Pg isn't running. The only match for `postgres` is the `grep postgres` command. You may need to start Pg. If it fails to start, check the PostgreSQL log files for information on why.

Comment: I saw a command after my PostgreSQL install that mentioned starting—will track that down and try it.

Will I have to manually "start" PosgreSQL every time I want to use it, or is this a once-per-install kind of start? (or maybe the PG gem handles this start each time I start my app server...?)

Comment: The pg gem certainly does not handle it. Beyond that, I don't know. I'd expect whatever packaging you use to start it via launchd, but couldn't say much more. On Mac OS X there seem to be at least three competing packagings of PostgreSQL in common use (Homebrew, Postgres.app and the official EnterpriseDB installer), making it a #!%# nightmare to support especially if, like me, you don't have a Mac. Apple won't permit VMs to be run on other systems so no Apple hardware = no access to OSX for testing. Experienced users of Pg on Apple stuff don't seem to answer questions here much.

Comment: I've grumped about the Mac OS X / pg situation on my blog. http://blog.ringerc.id.au/2012/09/postgresql-packaging-on-mac-os-x-is-mess.html

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that PostgreSQL is not running.  First I highly recommend backing up PostgreSQL db's before doing OS upgrades because sometimes things don't go well.  If you have a dump, you have a lot more options if things go south.  I do agree that recompiling on a new OS poses some questions regarding your existing dbs.

The first thing to do of course is to try to start PostgreSQL normally.  Maybe it is just missing a startup script.  Something like `sudo -u postgres pg_ctl -D /path/to/postgresql/data/dir`

If that doesn't work you need to look at the error message and try to resolve that.  Hopefully it works without problem.  If it doesn't work copy your data directory, if you can, to a system running the old version.  Try to dump it from there.  After you have your copy (important, back up files first!) you may see if you can get pg_upgrade to work.  If that fails, try to compile (via homebrew) the same major version you were running before.

If that fails, hire an expert.